# Enable back button on actionbarsherlock without extend it

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, return, back, baseadapter

I have a class that extends ListActivity and I can't extend my BaseAdapter.java.
Is there any quick fix to use the bar of BaseAdapter or to show the actionbarsherlock with the back arrow?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP, ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP);`

Comment: It say "The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type 
 MultipleItemsList", change to getActionBar(). With getActionBar() it appear but doesn't go back...

Comment: `getSupportActionBar()` is for ActionBarSherlock. If you aren't using it, it's `getActionBar()`. As for the navigation, try adding `android:parentActivityName` in the manifest entry for this Activity.

Comment: Thanks, I extended SherlockListActivity and I used your code, it works with the standard onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

on the onCreate() function add this line:

```
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

then add this method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case android.R.id.home:
         this.finish();
         break;

      // code here for other cases

   }
   return (true);
}
```